# How to open a file with with ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to open a file on rails user model with ruby and call it from user controller but it kept throwing me back wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1..3).

This is my file directory 'app' ,'assets', 'files', 'test_list.txt'
'app' ,'controllers', 'users controller'

can you help?thanks

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def self.my_method
    my_array = []

    file = File.join(Rails.root, 'app' 'models','assets', 'files', 'test_list.txt')
    File.open.each do |line|
      my_array << line.gsub!(/\n?/, "")
    end

    return my_array.to_s
  end
end
```

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  require 'open-uri'
  require 'net/http'

  def show
    # uri = URI('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Kalagan/3b26be21cbf65b62cf05ab549433314e/raw')
    #   data = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
    #   anagrams = data.split(/\n/)

    @vari = User.my_method
    @query = params[:query]
    @results = anagrams.select { |word| @query.split('').sort.join == word.split('').sort.join }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing nothing to the `open` method. Pass the filename

Change

```
File.open
```

to

```
File.open(file)
```

`open` method needs to know at least the filename it has to open

Comment: hi thanks for the answering, now it returns No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen

Comment: So that file does not exist :) check the pathname

Comment: hi Do you mean this as pathname ?file = File.join(Rails.root, 'app' 'models','assets', 'files', 'test_list.txt')

Comment: yes, if you get that error it means this file does not exist

Comment: @alie also that looks like a very stange path to a file ".../app/models/assets/files/..." are you sure `models` belongs in that path?

Comment: hi @engineersmnky do you this line here file = File.join(Rails.root, 'app' 'models','assets', 'files', 'test_list.txt') ??

Comment: yeah i am pretty sure thaat's not right, i am tring to call it from the controller, how sould I write it?

Comment: @alie where is the actual file located? If I had to guess you are looking for `Rails.root.join('app','assets','files','test_list.txt')` or `Rails.root.join('lib','assets','files','test_list.txt')`

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed a comma.You can write the below code.

`file = File.join(Rails.root, 'app', 'models','assets', 'files', 'test_list.txt')`

and for reading the content

```
File.read(file) do |file|
  file.each do |line|
    p line
  end
end
```